# Given a natural number N. What is the sum of the numbers N?

Tags: javascript

I tried to solve but didn't work :

```
const SumOf = (N) => {
  var res = N.toString().split("");
  var total = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    total += res[i]
  }
}
```

Comment: You're close. Change `i < N` to `i < res.length` and `total += res[i]` to `total += +res[i]` (additional `+` before `res[i]` to convert it to a number).

Comment: thank you it is working

Answer (score -1):

You can simply write:

```js
const sumN = (number) => {
  const nArray = number.split("").map(n=> +n)
  return nArray.reduce((acc, cur)=> acc+=cur, 0)
}

console.log(sumN("123"))
```